# Want an explanation about this code

Tags: c#

Im new to c#
 Im using this code to get screenshots of my desktop.
 But i dont get what do they mean.
here is the code.

```
bt = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
```

and

```
screenShot.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
```

can someone please explain me what these codes do and what they mean ?

specially the parts in the brackets..
Thanks.

Comment: This is why you shouldn't copy & paste code willy-nilly from the internet.

Comment: Apart from @Arran's remark, you can do a search on Google for every parameter passed to those methods.

Comment: Step 1. Learn C# properly.
Step 2. Use documentation for obvious stuff. For example, read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap(v=vs.110).aspx) what the first line means.

Comment: Or go directly to [msdn.microsoft.com](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.copyfromscreen(v=vs.110).aspx) and search there. Also, there are no "brackets" in your example. I assume you mean the parenthesis.

Comment: Have a look at MSDN for the `Bitmap` class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

`Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width` and `Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height` take the Width and Height of the current Screen (Monitor). They are used to create a new `Bitmap`.

The second Line copies the contents of a region (here: The whole screen).

Comment: and whats the meaning of "Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X" and "Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y" ?

Comment: Also "0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy"

Comment: if you really need that depth of description you should take a look at the msdn as stated in the comments. [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cdcw1c3b(v=vs.110).aspx) is the class you're looking for.

Comment: and the "0, 0" in my code means "Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X = 0" and "Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y = 0" ?